# Is it possible to copy format from other application into Silverlight RichTextBox?

Tags: silverlight, copy, richtextbox

Now I'm playing with the [RichTextBox](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=RichNotepadSnippets) in Silverlight.
I'm trying to copy some content from other application like Office Word. However all I can get is the pain TEXT without any format.
Is possible to copy the content from word or PDF file with the format like font-size, font-color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Silverlight 4, there's a limitation on the data you can get from the clipboard.

You are allowed to get the plain text from the clipboard but not the raw data itself (ex: images, rich text formated text, etc).

Until a new version of Silverlight allow you to get the raw data from the clipboard, I'm afraid it won't be possible, even with a third party RichTextBox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope the new version of Silverlight can support this.